# Images are not loading into recyclerView chosen from gallery

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, uri

Basically I'm using a image picker library from github for choosing multiple images from gallery.There is no problem in choosing images not even in getting uri but the uris are not loaded into recycler view. It's not showing any error or any other messages.

My Uri Getting Code:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        ArrayList<Uri> selected=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            selected.add(Uri.parse(images.get(i).path));
        }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selected.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selected);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

Adapter class code:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  //ivbackground is imageView

          Glide.with(holder.ivBackground.getContext())
                .load(image.get(position)).into(holder.ivBackground);}
```

Comment: First of all you should pass context from activity to recycler adapter and then can use like this `Glide.with(context).load(image.get(position)).into(holder.ivBackground);`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because drawable images are being loaded without any problem

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to how load from url have the "http://www." schema, the Uri should also provide proper schema, "file://". Maybe yours don't.
Try passing it as a file instead.

`Glide.with(holder.ivBackground.getContext())
                .load(new File(image.get(position))).into(holder.ivBackground);`